# When initializing a main window win32, when is the best time to show a modal dialog?

Tags: dialog, modal-dialog, postmessage, oncreate

I'm trying to accomplish this in Win32, but I'm sure the same rules apply in the world of WinForms.

**Q:** I create my main window, and then, when it is being shown, I want to show a modal dialog. The problem is; how can I know when the main window is completely initialized and visible? That is, exactly when is the best time to show the dialog?

**Ideas:**
1) Handle `WM_CREATE` and as a final step `PostMessage(WM_USER_MESSAGE)`. Handle `WM_USER_MESSAGE` and show modal dialog!

2) Handle `WM_CREATE` and set a timer at ~300 ms. Handle `WM_TIMER`, kill timer and show modal dialog!

3) Handle `WM_ACTIVATE`, if first activation `PostMessage(WM_USER_MESSAGE)`. Handle `WM_USER_MESSAGE` and show modal dialog!

4) Handle `WM_SHOWWINDOW`, if first-time show show modal dialog!

The above approaches work, but the result is not always that good. Is there a better method? Perhaps handling `WM_ENTERIDLE` or `WM_KICKIDLE` messages in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. exactly the best time to show the dialog is:

You can handle WM_CREATE and check for window handle is valid by using function:

```
:: GetSafeHwnd( m_hwnd)
```

And we can show modal dialog at that time.